# logrotate archive the dateext archived log files again

Tags: linux, logrotate

On my CentOS 6.5,

A couple of sites are running and I set logs directory separately.
loglotate works weekly but the results is not good. it archive already archived logs again every week.

here is /etc/logrotate.d/sites file.

```
/home/site1/logs/httpd/* /home/site2/logs/ httpd/* /home/site3/logs/httpd/* {
    copytruncate
    weekly
    rotate 4
    missingok
    notifempty
    dateext
}
```

and file list on /home/siate1/logs/httpd

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35100863 May 14 17:37 site1-access_log
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Apr 27 03:29 site1-access_log-20140413-20140420
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May  4 03:24 site1-access_log-20140413-20140420-20140427
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May 11 03:35 site1-access_log-20140413-20140420-20140427-20140504
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  70221784 May 11 03:35 site1-access_log-20140413-20140420-20140427-20140504-20140511
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Apr 27 03:29 site1-access_log-20140420
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May  4 03:24 site1-access_log-20140420-20140427
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May 11 03:35 site1-access_log-20140420-20140427-20140504
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  69335598 May 11 03:35 site1-access_log-20140420-20140427-20140504-20140511
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May  4 03:24 site1-access_log-20140427
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May 11 03:35 site1-access_log-20140427-20140504
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68505478 May 11 03:35 site1-access_log-20140427-20140504-20140511
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May 11 03:35 site1-access_log-20140504
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68772871 May 11 03:35 site1-access_log-20140504-20140511
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68054687 May 11 03:35 site1-access_log-20140511
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     24701 May 14 16:54 site1-error_log
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Apr 27 03:29 site1-error_log-20140413-20140420
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May  4 03:24 site1-error_log-20140413-20140420-20140427
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May 11 03:35 site1-error_log-20140413-20140420-20140427-20140504
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 109645452 May 11 03:35 site1-error_log-20140413-20140420-20140427-20140504-20140511
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Apr 27 03:29 site1-error_log-20140420
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May  4 03:24 site1-error_log-20140420-20140427
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May 11 03:35 site1-error_log-20140420-20140427-20140504
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     43345 May 11 03:35 site1-error_log-20140420-20140427-20140504-20140511
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May  4 03:24 site1-error_log-20140427
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May 11 03:35 site1-error_log-20140427-20140504
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     84371 May 11 03:35 site1-error_log-20140427-20140504-20140511
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May 11 03:35 site1-error_log-20140504
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     38442 May 11 03:35 site1-error_log-20140504-20140511
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     31182 May 11 03:35 site1-error_log-20140511
```

What is the problem?

Comment: This question probably belongs to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match is too broad. It should not match rotated files, but only the current logfile for each rotation group. Try `logs/httpd/*_log` rather than `logs/httpd/*` (if all log files actually end in `_log`). Refer to `man 7 glob` for details.

Comment: It's very simple but I missed!
I'll use serverfault.com for next similar topics later.
Thank you, Helmut.